# How does doubling tool proficiencies work?

Tags: dnd-5e, racial-traits

Recently I have reviewed the Aereni Wood Elf stat and found an entry modifying their elven training:

> *Aereni Training.* Choose one skill or tool proficiency. Your proficiency bonus is doubled for any ability check you make that uses
> this chosen proficiency.

**However, I am confused about what doubling my tool proficiency bonus would entail...** Would doubling my skills in cook utensils mean that people who eat my food gain +2 to every hit dice regained? Or are a Herbalist's potions twice as effective?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### When making an ability check using the tool, you add your twice your proficiency bonus to the result.

The feature you cite allows you to select a skill or tool proficiency. Thereafter, whenever you make an ability check with that skill or tool, the formula is:

> d20 + *ability modifier* + (2 x *Proficiency Bonus*)

I recommend reading through the basic rules for ability checks and proficiency bonus here: [Using Ability Scores: Proficiency Bonus](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/using-ability-scores#ProficiencyBonus).

Comment: I have read through that section many times both on the site and in print, though I am still at a loss. I guess my confusion would be on what part of "knowing how to cook" or "knowing how to make potions" would apply to an ability check... Is that what the DC table tied to each tool proficiency is about? (still trying to understand that.)

Comment: @VictorB The DM tells you if you can apply one of your proficiencies to an ability check.

Comment: Ah, so it doesn't mean "you can use the tools twice as well" but that your ability to apply such knowledge outside of the common uses (such as using your cooking skills to help an alchemist or sewing skills to stitch up a wound.) That makes a lot more sense. Thanks.

Comment: @VictorB   I’m not sure what you’re saying there. All it means is when the DM asks for the check, you add your proficiency twice to the d20 result. It doesn’t mean anything else.

Comment: How I understood tool proficiencies is "the ability to use the tools". In other words, you can't learn to cook just by buying the best kitchen gear.... However, when you said "when the DM asks for a check" it shifted my mindset from the tools to how one could apply it. For instance "Can I use apply my proficiency in tinker/weaver tools to my medicine check in order to suture up my friend's wound?" aka applying the skill and not the tools to a DM check.